# Android service stops working when phone locked

Tags: android

I have an application which starts a service. The service has a timer and pops a notification every 30 seconds. I notice the following behavior:

- if the screen is on the notifications are shown ok (even if the app is in background)
- if the screen is off (by power button or by itself) the notifications won't show
- if the screen is off but I have the debugging running the notifications appear

How can I make the service run with the screen off.

(The actual app only checks if a notification should be checked every 30 seconds, but for testing purposes, the above scenario is ok)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the some problem.

You may use the WakeLock to do the work!
Something like this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
          getApplicationContext().POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
wl.acquire();
```

Then use this:

```
wl.release();
```

to release the wakelock.

Don't forger to add:

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

to the manifest!

Comment: don't use this as it will drain the battery uselessly. Instead use the AlarmManager as indicated in another answer

Comment: @Marius can we use AlarmManager to wake up every 30s?

Comment: yes, just set the PendingIntent to (for example) start a service, and then have the AlarmManager repeat every 30 second.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. That would be the perfect way to quickly drain the phone's battery. If the phone is sleeping, let it sleep, unless you have a GOOD reason not to (in which case you use the AlarmManager for a one-time wake-up call in the future).

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but you need to use a completely different approach. A network tickle would be a good idea, for example, assuming you can live with your app being 2.2+ only.

Comment: @EdoMike I'm using code like this 
Context c = getApplicationContext();
        AlarmManager alarm = 
            (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);Intent i = new Intent(c, AlarmProxy.class);PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, 10000, sender);registerReceiver(alarmBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
but timer do not called every 10 seconds, How I can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want your service to run every 30s when the device is locked, you have to schedule your alarm with type [ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP) . But beware, this will certainly drain devices batteries to death rapidly!