# Android does not execute everything on night

Tags: android, save, android-service

I made a program that creates a Service.

The service connects to a website every 5 minutes, collects one line of data and outputs it to a file.

My problem is that it didn't collect the data every 5 minutes. The data was collected once in around 50-70min. Why? Is there something in android that prevents background services from running properly during nights? What is also strange to me, the 50-70 minute breaks happened only when I was not using my phone.

Times it collected the data:

```
1:40
1:45
1:50
1:55
2:00
2:05
2:10
2:15
2:20
2:25
2:30 I was awake until this.
3:20
4:15
5:00
6:05
6:55
7:55
8:45
10:20
10:50 Woke up at here.
10:55
```

Comment: The answers gave you the technical reason but keep in mind some devices have a battery saver mode. If this is engaged then your service may not be able to connect even if you implement these changes. Design your application such that it can deal with gaps in the data and request missing chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are not surprising. Android was designed to swipe out (and back in) processes based overall level of resource as well as other factors.

Modifying your service to **become a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)** will certainly improve your results:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Foreground services are basically services guaranteed by Android to be less susceptible to swipe out, 
which is what you want.

But even a foreground service will halt its processing when the devices goes to sleep. And, if you feel your polling logic is important enough so to keep the device from sleeping, **you should also [acquire a wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)**.

Note: Long running wakelocks have a *huge* impact of on battery usage. Handle with care!

Finally, please **consider using an [alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for your task.** Alarms are usually considered better option for
long running polling tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of an approach you use to schedule your updates, the OS [might](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) shift updates to decrease battery drain and overall burden. [Delayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) tasks might be postponed if the device falls into deep sleep (happens at night mostly as the device is inactive during long periods of time).

Answer (score 0):

It's done this way to prevent your battery to be drained to fast. If you really want to wake your device every 5 minutes, you can check [the answer to this post and use the AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139313/android-service-stops-working-when-phone-locked)